# How to use Higan 094 on Ubuntu?

Tags: controllers, emulation, ubuntu

I'm new to linux so I'm having some problems.

I installed higan emulator (I'm running a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.10 in a windows 8 notebook) to play some SNES games but at launch it said I had some problem with OpenGL 3.2 and it asked me to change in Settings->Advanced Options. The problem is that higan only gives me a black screen and a library screen. So how am I supposed to access settings? (there is no button, no nothing).

Searching in internet I found the Settings.bml file (~/.config/higan folder) and changed the Driver: OpenGL space to Driver: SDL and I could run the game just fine. But now I need to map my USB controller to play the game. There is a input.bml file but I don't know what to write to map my controller.

So, can someone help me

1. open/find the settings in Higan, so i can use the program's mapping tool

or

2. teach how to manually map the controller? (what do I write in the input.bml file?)

Thx

Comment: Hey, I'm glad you figured this out. However, to make *this site* work well, please click the "Answer Your Question" button and put the answer there. This question will not count as answered if you just put the answer in the question.

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting used to this site

Comment: Crosspost: http://askubuntu.com/q/599588/184892

Comment: Is it a problem? I did not know where it was better to ask. If so, sry! (If one needs to be deleted, I'd suggest keeping the other one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: Ok, I went to a friend's house and he showed me how dumb I was.

1. As I said, I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm used to Windows' UI, so I always forget that, in the Ubuntu's UI, the menus are located in the top left area of the screen and not in the program's window. So I was able to enter the settings menu and map my controller
2. In Higan, the mapping is translated to something like this '1/Button/9'. The first number is some kind of controller ID and the following maps the buttons. My controller ID happens to be 64db7df00e8f0003. My second question was if somebody knew how to get this number. Using the 'evtest' it says: 'Input device ID: BUS 0x3 vendor 0xe8f product 0x3 version 0x110', so I see where some parts of the ID comes from. After some search I found this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/366994/how-to-identify-game-controller-for-sdl2-in-ubuntu I wasn't able to compile the code (as I said, I'm still new to linux) but I think the ID must be this GUID or something like it.